# hide or show div, destroy function on hover

Tags: jquery, function, hover

I am trying to unbind a specific function on a hover event.
A div is shown on page load and fades out after 5 seconds unless that div has been hovered over.

How come the function isn't destroyed? I have tried: .off, destroy

The code:

```
function fadeOutshowBox (){

    $('#showBox').delay(5000).fadeOut();

}



fadeOutshowBox ();

$('#showBox').hover (function(){

        $(this).unbind(fadeOutshowBox);

});
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yes, the fadeOut animation has to be stopped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you only want to animate the div in case it isn't hovered for 5 seconds.

In that case, this should do the trick:

```
function fadeOutshowBox (){
    return setTimeout(function(){
        $('#showBox').fadeOut();
    }, 5000);
}

var handle = fadeOutshowBox();

$('#showBox').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(handle);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/axbccfuv/

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$('#showBox').hover (function(){

        $(this).fadeToggle();

});
```

and you can take a look at https://api.jquery.com/unbind/

unbind using for unbind event not unbind function

Answer (score 0):

fadeOutshowBox isn't bound at all. unbinding it doesn't do anything.

How about this: 
Define the function fadeOutshowBox, which does the fade out (without the delay), and then call that function after a setTimeout (or delay). meanwhile, if the user hovers, fadeOutshowBox can be redefined to do nothing.

```
function fadeOutshowBox() {
    $('#showBox').fadeOut();
}

setTimeout(fadeOutshowBox,5000);

$('#showBox').hover (function(){
    fadeOutshowBox = function(){};
});
```

I haven't tested it, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cancel a delay function, you should use setTimeout instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout